# Can I add a Node to a WebView

Tags: javafx-2

I'm guessing this isn't possible, but . . . Anybody know if there's a way to add a javafx.scene.Node to a javafx.scene.web.WebView?

My primary concern is that the Node is visible within the DOM. Ideally it would be treated in the dom as a div, but that's not my primary concern.

Answer (score 1):

When you talk about dom and div, these are html components and tags. Node is a Java. It cannot be visible or treated "as is" directly in html. However you can bridge it:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    WebView webView = new WebView();
    final WebEngine webEngine = webView.getEngine();
    webEngine.load(getClass().getResource("demo.html").toExternalForm());

    webEngine.getLoadWorker().stateProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Worker.State>() {
        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Worker.State> ov, Worker.State oldState, Worker.State newState) {
            if (newState == Worker.State.SUCCEEDED) {
                JSObject window = (JSObject) webEngine.executeScript("window");
                window.setMember("myJavaFXButton", new Button("My JavaFX Button"));
            }
        }
    });

    StackPane root = new StackPane();
    root.getChildren().addAll(webView);
    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

where the demo.html is,

```
<div id="content">content</div>
<button onclick="document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = myJavaFXButton.getText();">
     Get my lovely JavaFX button's text
</button>
```